# Wordpress error when adding an order: "Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page"

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have Woocommerce installed on my Wordpress website and have never had this problem before. Adding orders manually through "Add order" has always worked fine – I added an order manually 2 days ago – but today (after nothing has changed), I am getting an error that says "Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page".

I've tried the usual of deactivating plugins/themes but nothing seems to work, I can't seem to find the problem. I've ensured all plugins are up to date etc. and that doesn't work either. Does anyone have any other ideas?

Comment: Are you loged in as admin?

Comment: This typically indicates that the usermeta capabilities are broken in the database.

Answer (score 1):

Install this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/members/ and check your role and capabilities.
Maybe some plugins or code has remove your capabilities to access Order